# Is there a way to use a preprocessor macro inside of another function-like macro?

Tags: c, macros, clang, c-preprocessor

I found a neat Clang-specific feature that lets you know if a header exists before actually including it (`__has_include`).  I was trying to come up with my own macro to do something like the following:

```
#define DOES_HEADER_EXIST(_header_)      \
#if !__has_include(_header_)             \
#warning Header not found: _header_      \
#endif
```

but this does not seem to work. I can see why this would not work, as it's kind of like asking the preprocessor to do two passes, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to create a macro that will expand into a preprocessor directive that the preprocessor will actually take action on.

Your particular macro is flawed because it expands into a single long line that would have been considered a malformed `#if` directive, if the compiler would have allowed the `#` to be followed by a token that wasn't a macro parameter.

To do what you want, you will need a pre-preprocessor that injects the tests you want to perform before you actually compile the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use macros in macros, but not preprocessor keywords, unfortunately.